# Sending image from android to Mvc4 WebAPI

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I want to send image from android through Web API to windows server file system. There would be bulk use of this API or process for uploading images. So, Please help me out what should be the best approach for this ?

I tried converting image to base64 in android and then sending it to API but i was not getting proper base 64 and i found this a dicey approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/) is the solution for my problem.

Comment: I am using MIME for sending photos from android to windows server file system through asp.net WEB API 2.

Please Update if any other best solution is there .